# Problem when moving bone

Tags: rigging, hair

[image]i've been strugglin with my hair paticule on my character , wich i've been attach to the skin and the skin have been attach to some clothes . I finaly finnish doing a basic rigging on the character but when i'm moving arm or else the hair dont move along with the hair (instead move up and down ) . I've been trying to weight paint the vertex group but nothing is happening , only the skin and clothes have been affect by it . Please could you help me out ! Peace !

Comment: Please upload modifiers screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you applied an armature on the particles system based mesh by default armature appeared at the end of modifiers, Please have a look of image below:

[image]

Please move up Armature modifier on top of particles modifiers and your hair should be follow the armature

Please take a look of image below:
[image]

Comment: You may mark the answer as correct, as may be helpful for somebody else.
how to you want to intouch, I usually logged in to this forum daily and also everybody is ready to help :)

Comment: Cool man I wish i could found that forum earlier . I'll be asking questions on here then , thanks for your time bro

Comment: Welcome and thank you for being so kind, yes this form is very helpful to everybody, I liked too and learned a lot here :)